# Can't enable syn cookies

Tags: linux

I am trying to enable syn cookies in a server, but I can't.

```
root@server [~]# echo '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies
root@server [~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies
0
root@server [~]#
```

What is wrong, and how could I enable syn cookies?

Comment: Are there any log messages (dmesg, kern, syslog)? `sysctl net.inet.tcp.syncookies` does say the same thing? Is `/proc` really the `/proc` you expect (this stands for the basic questions like mountpoints set up properly and not just writing to some directory structure that looks like `/proc`)

Comment: @ServerHorror `/proc` is the `/proc` I expect, `sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies` outputs `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 0` and `dmesg` outputs nothing.

Comment: Is this a physical server or a virtual server?

Comment: @Janne Pikkarainen It is a virtual server.

Comment: What is the output of `lsattr /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies`

Comment: @mossy `lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies`